# Can you sort DayOfWeek Enumeration

Tags: vb.net, enumeration, dayofweek

I am trying to figure out if the DayOfWeek Enumeration list can be sorted by using the integer value (ie Sunday = 0). Ultimately I want to take the DayOfWeek Enumeration list and population a dropdownlist with the days of the week from Sunday - Monday and I do not want to hard code the items in the HTML markup. Is this possible?

Comment: I put the language in the tags, its VB.net

Comment: I must be going blind, I just could not see them. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to bind the [`DayOfWeek` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) to a `DropDownList`?

This should work, although i wouldn't use an enum as `DataSource` for a DropDownList:

```
Dim days = From d In Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
            Select New With {
                .DayName = [Enum].GetName(GetType(DayOfWeek), d),
                .DayNumber = d
            }
Me.DdlDays.DataSource = days
Me.DdlDays.DataTextField  = "DayName"
Me.DdlDays.DataValueField = "DayNumber"
Me.DdlDays.DataBind()
```

This is sorted by the integer value by default, hence it starts with `Sunday`. You could change it easily with an `Order By`.

Comment: Oh I am not planning on binding the enum, I am going to put the DayOfWeek names into a string array and then bind the array to the drop down list. Thank you for you help